# Why I am getting forbidden error during model call in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My controller, if I run this, it works properly

```
class Front_controller extends CI_Controller{ 
   public function index(){ 
      $this->load->view('front/index'); 
   } 
}
```

if I call model

```
class Front_controller extends CI_Controller{

   public function  index(){
      $data['list'] = $this->Mymodel->getdata(); 
      $this->load->view('front/index',$data); 
   } 
}
```

it gives :

> 403 forbidden error and 500 internal server error

Comment: enable error reporting to know errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the model before using it, like this:

```
$this->load->model('Mymodel');
$this->Mymodel->mymodelmethod();
```

More info here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
    class Front_controller extends CI_Controller{
       public function  index(){
          $this->load->model('Mymodel');
          $data['list'] = $this->Mymodel->getdata(); 
         $this->load->view('front/index',$data); 
     }
    }
```

Before use of `model` in CI, you need to load that model by using the method `$this->load->model('modelName');`